# Reverse select_related for onetoone field not working

Tags: django

According to the docs then you should be able to catch reverse relations when those relations are onetoone with a select_related(). But it is not working, so what could I be missing?

My class looks like this:

```
class MainPage(models.Model):
    book = models.OneToOneField(Book, primary_key=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I can do this fine:

```
book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id, active=True)
main_page = book.mainpage
```

But doing like so does not lower the database calls:

```
book = Book.objects.select_related('mainpage').get(id=book_id, active=True)
main_page = book.mainpage
```

Comment: Hey, please leave a feedback (i.e. either upvote, or downvote, or leave a comment) to the answer. It will only help us in answering / writing better: http://blog.codinghorror.com/how-to-write-without-writing/

Comment: Per https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7270 this should be possible, but as of Django 1.9 I still can't get the select_related to work on a one-to-one reverse relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you intend to hit only a single sql query (using one to one join). This might work for that:

```
book = Book.objects.get(mainpage__book_id=book_id, active=True)
```

**EDIT:**

The query in your question does not work because `select_related` works only with the querysets while `.get` returns an instance object. Thus this should work:

```
book = Book.objects.select_related('mainpage').filter(id=book_id, active=True)[0]
main_page = book.mainpage
```

Comment: Actually, you _can_ use this with a get; it's just that the `get` needs to be the last piece in the ORM call: ```book = Book.objects.select_related('mainpage').get(id=book_id, active=True)```